# How to comment properties of a class for Visual Studio intellisense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I know using /// to comment a function is the right way, and it also works for properties as shown by the following code

```
/// <summary>
/// This is for demo
/// </summary>
public class Foo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description A (working for intellisense)
    /// </summary>
    public int iA { get; set; }

    /// Description B (not working for intellisense)
    public int iB { get; set; }

    public int iC { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to comment class properties for intellisense than the ///  which is 3 lines minimum.

Comment: Can't format this in a comment. See my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just XML. You can do it in one line if you want to.

```
/// <summary>Description A (working for intellisense)</summary>
public int iA { get; set; }
```

Comment: The fact that it *is* XML is also why stripping out the `<summary>` tags doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can you [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) which generates some simple but useful comments automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Recommended Tag for property in Documentation is <value> as per official .NET Guide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/value

```
/// <value>The Name property gets/sets the value of the string field, _name.</value>
```